# How to ignore a folder when merging source in mercurrial

Tags: merge, mercurial, tortoisehg, mergetool

I have using mercurial version control for my project.
Now I want to merge source from branch A to branch B.

And my questions are:

- Is there any way to ignore some folder when merging source?
- Or is there any way can I specify a folder to merge?

I searched Google for my issue but only find how to ignore files.

Can anyone help me in this issue?
Thanks you so much

Comment: Why is this question tagged as `svn`?

Comment: "ignore some folder but files" is hardly understandable, sorry. Rewrite or explain it better, maybe in longer English words

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are forking a folder in the project. one option is to add the folder in your `.hgrc` file to always use local file during merge

```
[merge-patterns]
path/to/folder/* = internal:local
```

Comment: I have tried as your comment but all of sources are merged successfully. I added more content to hgrc file as below:                                                                                                  [merge-patterns]
path/to/folder_need_merge/* = internal:local                                                         I wonder if I whether did right or not.                                                    Thanks

Comment: to merge successfully was the expected behavior, it always preserves your local changes ( per your second question). If you wanted to ignore that folder entirely so that it does not get pushed, you can add the folder to `.hgignore`

Comment: mercurial also supports nested repos in case you want to version control them independently while keeping the folder structure